# How do I fill a pixel by a specific color depending on a line on a txt file, then make an image via all of the pixels in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

If i'm very unclear, what I mean is the following:
I have a text file, and in  the text file, there are a bunch of lines that are rgb color values. And then the program will do the following:
On line one on the txt file, it will tell the program how big the file will be (as in resolution, not in gigabytes and stuff like that). On line 2 it would fill the first pixel of an image (the one in the top left corner) with the rgb value on line one on the text file. On line 3, it would fill the pixel below pixel 1. On line 4 it would fill the pixel below pixel 2. On line 5, so on and so forth. In the end, the program will make some kind of image with all of those pixels.

Now, my question is: is this applicable in pygame? Like, with all of those pixel places, you can then make a surface for a sprite? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do.

You can create a `pygame.Surface` with the dimensions given, then use the values of the other lines in a nested for loop, setting pixels using `surface.set_at((x, y), color)` (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at)

This will be slow, though, especially for larger surfaces

> is this applicable in pygame?

I have no idea why you would do it like this. `pygame.image.load()` supports many popular image formats. If you want something that can be loaded and saved, `pygame.image.save()` also exists and works.

If you add anything about what exact problem you're trying to solve by doing this, maybe I can suggest something more specific.